# How do I include an Objective C category in a RubyMotion project

Tags: objective-c, rubymotion

In my Xcode projects I have sometimes used a category for adding zoom level functionality to MKMapView. Now I want use the category in my RubyMotion project. The files are in the vendor dir and I have included them with

```
app.vendor_project('vendor', :static)
```

It looks like the compilation goes ok, but ld complains that

```
ld: in /Users/admin/gitrep/bgApp/vendor/build-iPhoneSimulator/libvendor.a, 
archive has no table of contents for architecture i386
```

Does anyone know if this approach for including categories (and possibly also stand alone classes) work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. With Xcode, create a project as "Cocoa Touch Static Library" and put your codes into this project.
2. Put this project into your `vendor/`.
3. Then write like this in Rakefile to use in RubyMotion.

Rakefile

```
  app.vendor_project('vendor/UIFoo-Bar',
                 :xcode,
                 :headers_dir => 'UIFoo-Bar')
```